# Linear Optimization: Minimum Cost Network Flow Model

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

Consider the directed graph G=(V,A) where each directed arc (i,j) $\in A$ has associated with it a distance $d_{ij}$. Formulate a  minimum cost network flow model that will identify the shortest paths and their lengths from 1 to every o[image]ther vertex in G.

(From Rader page 83)

My original idea was that wanted to minimize $\sum_{j=2}^{7}d_{1j}$ but that doesn't work because that doesn't take the correct paths into account.

The constraints are a little easier but I'm not sure what to do for the minimization equation

Answer (score 0):

Define your decision variable $f_{ij}$ as the flow along arc $(i,j)$. Let node 1 be the supply node ($s$), and pick a node other than 1 as your demand ($d$). Then, your MCNF problem is simply
$$ \min \sum_i \sum_j d_{ij}f_{ij}$$
subject to:
$$ \sum_i f_{ij} - \sum_i f_{ji} = 
\begin{cases} 
-1, \text{if } j = s\\
+1, \text{if } j = d\\
0, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The constraints enforce flow balance: supply has to send 1, demand has to get it, everything else is intermediate so whatever comes in has to leave. The flow balance is written as (inflow - outflow). Because your constraint matrix is totally unimodular, the flow decision variables will be integral, in particular either 0 or 1 because of the RHS of the constraints. Since they're either 0 or 1, they act as switches for your objective function, turning "on" only your traveled path, which is accrued to your running total and minimized.